# Convert yyymmddhhmmss to usable datetime?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has a column with timestamps in it.  Here is an example:

```
20160111075400140935
20160111075400140934
20160111075400140933
20160111075400140932
```

I want to convert these to a usable Excel format with date *and* time.

Based on another SO question, I am using `=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),MID(B2,7,2))` to get the date.  I can also use `=TIME(MID(B2,9,2),MID(B2,11,2),MID(B2,13,2))` to get the time.  The problem is that I can't seem to get them in the same column.  I've tried a couple things:

```
=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),MID(B2,7,2))&TIME(MID(B2,9,2),MID(B2,11,2),MID(B2,13,2))
```

Results in `423800.329166666666667` no matter how I format the cell.

```
=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),MID(B2,7,2))&TIME(MID(B2,9,2),MID(B2,11,2),MID(B2,13,2))
```

Results in `42380 0.329166666666667` no matter how I format the cell.

I also tried putting each value in it's own column and combining the cells in various ways and got the same results as above.

The format I'm trying to use is `m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss`

Comment: Almost. use `+` instead of `&`   : `=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),MID(B2,7,2))+TIME(MID(B2,9,2),MID(B2,11,2),MID(B2,13,2))`  Then format it the way you want.

Comment: /facepalm!  Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `&` it will concatenate the two into a text string.  To get a number that can be formatted properly use `+` instead. This will add the two numbers together.

```
=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),MID(B2,7,2))+TIME(MID(B2,9,2),MID(B2,11,2),MID(B2,‌​13,2))
```

Using your numbers it will return the number: `42380.329166666666667`

The format it into the desired format.